# sequelize migrations sql output

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Using sequelize migrations .

Is there a solution to get an sql output file when running the migration ? So that one can see or save or re-use the generated sql ?

I don't know how to manage this with queryInterface .

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to set `logging: true` in connection properties for migrations?

Answer (score 1):

When you use migration there is config.js file there you have to enable logging.
here is my project config.js file

```html
require("dotenv").config();
module.exports = {
    development: {
        username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
        logging: false
    },
    test: {
        username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
        logging: true

    },
    master: {
        username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: process.env.DB_CONNECTION
    }
};
```